# Using a wildcard IP Address to get a Domain Name

Tags: java, ip

I am trying to write a class that will return a domain name from an IP Address that is in my /etc/hosts file. For example I know a block of IP Address which Google own are `74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255` and in my hosts file I have;

```
74.125.24.155   Google
74.125.24.101   Google
74.125.24.102   Google
74.125.24.132   Google
74.125.24.113   Google
74.125.24.84   Google
```

I have wrote a simple piece of code that will look to the hosts file and search for the name of the corresponding IP Address. Here is the code;

```
String destination = "74.125.24.84";
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(destination);
String resolvedHost = address.getHostName();
System.out.println("Translated " + destination + " to host name " + resolvedHost);
```

That will return the following `Translated 74.125.24.84 to host name Google`.
I then tried;

```
String destination = "74.125.24.*";
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(destination);
String resolvedHost = address.getHostName();
System.out.println("Translated " + destination + " to host name " + resolvedHost);
```

But got the following error in response;

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: 74.125.24.*
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
at IPToDomainName.main(IPToDomainName.java:12)
```

Is there a way that I can use a wildcard to represent Googles IP addresses?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? This is exactly the opposite of what domain names try to achieve. I suspect if you describe your actual goal, there will be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: We have a router in which it collects IP Addresses of the websites that people connected to the WiFi are viewing. From that we can chart this, show how many people visited what website, but the result is only showing the IP Address. I have had the /etc/hosts file edited but there is always more IP Addresses

Comment: why dont you feed the collected ip address to an prog and get host name list to create charts

Comment: Afraid that is out of my hands, I am just a small cog in a big machine and just trying to solve this issue that was given to me

Comment: @dan why are you putting things in the host file? Your code should do reverse DNS without putting anything in host file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you iterate through it?

```
for (int i=0;i<=255;i++) {
    String destination = "74.125.24." + i;
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(destination);

    if (address == null) // Or any exception.
         continue;

    String resolvedHost = address.getHostName();

    System.out.println("Translated " + destination + " to host name " + resolvedHost);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use `i` in that loop. I suspect you mean `"74.125.24." + i;`. You also might need to include the `255` value, at least according to the question.

Comment: check address null before gethostname :)